# How do I add basic properties to something like the Image class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to add a few basic properties to an image.  I would normally do this by doing

```
public class ExtendedImage: Image
{
}
```

But ofcourse this isn't allowed because it's sealed.

What other ways can I do this? The reason I want to extend Image, is because I'm looking to dynamically create and destroy objects, which get dragged and dropped around the application.  So I want to add manipulation handlers, and gestures, as well as adding and removing the object from various display objects.

I don't believe I'm able to inject an instance of Image into my base class, because then the data and the image will be decoupled when I try to have my dynamically created images respond to various manipulation events etc.    (Based on the location the image is placed on in the main canvas, I need it to have different functionality.

Any advice on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check my edited answer. You could use the Tag property to get things done.

Comment: @PaulSasik Trying that now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Tag property to associate instances and get the kind of behavior you desire. Something like:

```
public class ExtendedImageController
{
    // add methods and properties as necessary
}

// client code
var img = new Image(); // ...
img.Tag = new ExtendedImageController(img); // with reference to image

// in some event handler:
var ctrl = (ExtendedImageController)img.Tag;
ctrl.DoCleanupThings(); 
// ...
```

Comment: @Bob: You'll have to implement the same interfaces as the Image class and forward the property and method calls to the image object.

Comment: @Bob: Specifically in this case, you should inherit from FrameworkElement and compose with the image. See the code update.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anyway to make the _baseImage visible.. :(

Comment: @Bob: Just got another idea. Go ahead and add Image objects to your UI controls but use the FrameworkElement.Tag property to hold a reference to a "Contoller" object which could contain a reference to the Image and deal with it as you want it to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7429/discussion-between-paul-sasik-and-bob)