# Window.Current.Activated not fired on every UI interaction

Tags: c#, xaml, events, uwp

I am working on UWP application and I'm having a logic that depends on application focus gain/loss:

```
    ...

Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
    ...
//My code depends on this flag
public bool IsViewCurrentlyInFocus { get; private set; }

private void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    IsViewCurrentlyInFocus = e.WindowActivationState != CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated;
}
```

What I've notice is that user can interact with my application (for instance: scrolling the listview) although the event isn't raised - only when tapping/clicking on the page...

How can I determine that some sort of interaction is made with my application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Occurs when a window becomes the foreground window.

In a nutshell, this is a `Window` event, it does not affect the elements within the window. In your scenario, you can make use of the `IsActive` property to determine whether your `Window` is being used. For individual elements, I would suggest using the `GotFocus` event and `IsFocused` property respectively.

If you are specifically trying to detect the scroll in a `ListView`, this isn't possible, however you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248171/detect-scrolling-event-of-listbox).